# Heapsort in python

Tags: python, sorting, heapsort

For some reason, my heap sort is running a couple orders slower than it should be:

```
def heapsort(unsrt):
   if len(unsrt) == 1:
      return unsrt
   elif len(unsrt) == 2:
      if (unsrt[0] > unsrt[1]):
         unsrt.append(unsrt.pop(0))
      return unsrt
   for i in range((len(unsrt)-2)/2,-1,-1):
      root = i
#      print unsrt
      while True:
         left = root * 2 + 1#left child
         rght = left+1      #right child
         if len(unsrt)-1 < rght: #if you've reached the end
            break
         if len(unsrt) >= rght and unsrt[left] < unsrt[rght]:
            left += 1
            rght += 1
         if unsrt[root] < unsrt[left]:
            unsrt[root], unsrt[left] = unsrt[left], unsrt[root]
            root = left
         else:
            break

   unsrt.append(unsrt.pop(0))
   unsrt[:-1] = heapsort(unsrt[:-1])
   return unsrt
```

I believe it is running at n^2 (log n)^2, but I'm not sure how to reduce the order. Is there a way I can get this down into the proper order? `unsrt` is an unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is coming from this line:

```
unsrt.append(unsrt.pop(0))
unsrt[:-1] = heapsort(unsrt[:-1])
```

Basically, and if I understand correctly your implementation, you are heapifying the array at every call, getting the max, putting it on the last element in the array and then doing the work again.

I can identify 3 issues here:

1. `pop(0)` runs in **O(n)**, since you are calling it **n** times, that's your **O(n²)**
2. `unsrt[:-1]` creates a copy of the list which is also **O(n)** even though it is very fast due to memory optimization, still it's a waste of time
3. This one I am not 100% sure about it, correct me if I'm wrong. Your heapify algorithm runs in **O(nlogn)** and you are running it **n** time, again that's **O(n² logn)**. You should instead heapify the array once which can be done in **O(nlogn)** (actually it can be done in **O(n)**) then remove the minimum **n** times. Removing an element from the heap can be done in O(logn) time. so the total operation will be done in **O(nlogn)**

So here's what I would do:

1. Write the heapify function alone (make one such as the head is the minimum)
2. write the remove min function alone
3. In the sort function, simply heapify the array once and remove the minimum **n** times.

Using this solution, you will never have to translate elements in the array. When you delete an element from the heap, it is automatically pushed to the last unsorted position in the array.